# "Time ago" from "date end" in views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

How to print Date Field in Views in format "time ago" for "end dates"?
If I config field in views like:
Display: End date only,
Formatter: Time ago.
I get duration form Start date :(

Example for today (7 jun 2014).
date field values: start 1 jan 2013, end 1 jan 2014.
I wanna get: Expired - 5 mounths and 7 days.
But views printing: Expired - 1 year, 5 mounths and 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this in javascript to avoid caching issues and use the users machine time.

https://drupal.org/project/timeago

http://momentjs.com/

http://timeago.yarp.com/

otherwise there is a patch here: https://drupal.org/node/2026545

Comment: Thanks for the idea of conversion using js. 

I looked module "timeago". Great module, but it is impossible translate the strings (plurals strings). And there is a problem with the date fields if option "all day" is enabled. 

I'll try a custom js whit Drupal.formatPlural() or will use momentjs.com (looks powerfully).


Sorry for my english.