# How to use the Time ago view formatter when you have an end date collected in your date field?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a date field in a content type with a collected "**end date**" and I want to show the end date in a view with the **Time ago** view formatter.

The problem is that I don't find where to select the **end date** only display, like in the **date and time** formatter. Because when I select the **Time ago** formatter, I don't see the options for select the **end date**. So when I go to see the view output the **Time ago** always use the "**start date**".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Time ago" from "date end" in views](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116520/time-ago-from-date-end-in-views)

Comment: @oksana-c is not a duplicate because the Pierre.Vriens answer have the solution, it's a bug ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer if you looked at the link in the comment, you would realize that the answer there contains the link to the same issue that Pierre.Vriens posted in his answer, as well as other solutions. Also, the DO issue that Pierre.Vriens linked to is NOT a bug, but a feature request. So in fact there is nothing wrong with the Date module as the formatter requested in current question was not planned in module's functionality originally. And - Yes - this question is a duplicateof the one that I linked to.

Comment: @oksana-c yes, I see, sorry, y don't click in the link to see that is the same page (the drupal.org link), thanks for your comment

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer my intent is to share useful info helpful to others

Comment: @oksana-c that's the point here, sorry, I will read more slow for the next, and thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the issue about "[Date field's interval formatter always uses start date](https://www.drupal.org/node/2026545)". It seems pretty close to what you're struggling with.

[Comment # 9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2026545#comment-9521329) in that issue also contains a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/date-interval-formatter-end-date-2026545-9.patch) ...

Comment: thanks for this answer, I had this error once time ago, but this was solved deleting the field and creating two separate fields. And this come to my mind: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/165900/28275

Answer (score 3):

This not will solve the "realy" problem with the bug, but is a way:

If you are in a early stage of your project and you don't want use the patch you can delete the field and create two separated fields:

- initial_date
- final_date

I test it and this works fine.

If you want, you can read this: [When should I use collect an end date for a field, instead of using 2 separated date fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/165900/28275)

I will add an explanation in the question about this bug.